# Facebook UI fbml.dialog

Tags: facebook, user-interface, dialog

I can't manage to close a dialog box opened in an application. Here's my code:

```
FB.ui({
method:'fbml.dialog',
'display': 'dialog',
fbml:'<fb:dialog-button type="button" value="No" close_dialog="true" />',
size: {width:640,height:480}, width:640, height:480});
});
```

I can open the popup but no button is displayed.  Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everythings allright with the initialization of the fb library heres the code that worked for me.

```
FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size = {width:350, height:50};
          FB.ui({
            method:'fbml.dialog',
            display: 'dialog',
            fbml: (
                   '<div class="pop_content" id="pop_content">'+
                        '<h2 class="dialog_title"><span>HEADER TITLE</span></h2>'+
                        '<div class="dialog_content">'+
                            '<div class="dialog_body">CONTENT IN THE ALERT</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'

                   ),
            width: '350',
            height: '50'
          });
```

Greetings.